# How to get data from class name inside a id name in excel VBA?

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

How can I get data from the classes `date` and `number` (all 3) data?

[image: HTML code]

```vb
Sub Fii_dii()
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/fii_dii_market_today.htm"

    While IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'Copy data
    MsgBox IE.Document.all.Item("fiiTable").innerText
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are retrieved by the browser dynamically from another URI you can find in the network tab of the browser when refreshing the page. I would simply issue an xmlhttp request (faster and no browser) and use css class selectors to match on the required nodes by class. Loop the returned nodeList and write out to Excel

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ScrapeValues()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, values As Object, i As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/equities/htms/fiiEQ.htm", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set values = html.querySelectorAll(".date, .number")

    For i = 0 To values.Length - 1
        With ws
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = values.Item(i).innerText
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

---

If you want to use IE you need to have a test for those elements to be present and a timed loop e.g.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ScrapeValues()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, values As Object, i As Long, ws As Worksheet, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5 '<==adjust time here

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/fii_dii_market_today.htm"
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        t = Timer
        Do
            Set values = .document.querySelectorAll(".date, .number")
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While values.Length = 0

        If values.Length > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To values.Length - 1
                With ws
                    .Cells(i + 1, 1) = values.Item(i).innerText
                End With
            Next
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

--

**References (VBE>Tools>References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft Internet Controls